# Android - Strange behavior with different screen resolutions

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, resolution, vga

I'm having some problem with screen resolutions in Android.

I found the problem when I first ran my application on a VGA AVD and the application's images did not occupy the % of the screen I was expecting them to. I tried to run it on HVGA and QVGA and found out that they all occupied the exact same % of the screen, as if the screen resolution was the same.

In fact, resolution was the same: I debugged my program and checked the width and height when onSizeChanged was called, and got the same values for all the AVDs (320 x 430, or 320 x 483 for wide resolutions). I created some AVDs and manually set their resolution, but the behavior did not change.

My activity's content view, that is giving me these wrong resolutions, is a class which inherits from View.

Comment: Are you trying to support Android versions 1.5 and above?  Android uses a compatibility tool that caused problems when I tried to span both.  As a result I had to leave 1.5 users behind with a stable version, and explicity not support cupcake in my newer releases.

Comment: Actually I tested it on virtual devices from version 1.5 to version 2.2, but the problem persisted in all of them.

Comment: You need to provide more information in order for someone to help you.  What configuration do you have in your manifest about handling screen sizes?  What is the min and max sdk versions you are supporting?  What layout are you having problems with?

Comment: I haven't changed the manifest, it is the same since the project was created; no tags, attributes or elements were added or changed, so there's no configuration about screen size there. The application will support all sdk versions, and I tested it using every AVD I could create in the AVD Manager, from sdk 1.5 up to sdk 2.2. The layout I'm using is a class that inherits from View, all the drawing is handled on my implementation of its onDraw().

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, adding a "minSdkVersion" to my AndroidManifest.xml solved it.